# htaccess: exluce some domain in RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess

this is my .htaccess code
so if the user type just domain.com will be redirected to www.domain.com

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

my problem now is that i have a new domain pointing to the same domain path
so even the new domain is redirected "transparently" to domain.com...

how can i exclude some domain name from that rule?

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try making the rewrite generic, so all requests that are not starting with `www` are redirected, but on the correct/requested domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or, you can check instead for if the domain starts with `domain.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com [L,R=301]
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. Can you describe the code part by part? Just first code.

Comment: Great answer.  Explaining your syntax in detail would make this an _excellent_ answer.  Just saying. :)

Comment: The OP was trying to redirect multiple domains to the same path, however the original `RewriteCond` was specifically looking for a single domain (e.g. www.domain.com). My first example, will redirect any domain, that doesn't start with a `www.` to the requested path with the `www.` prepended. The `RewriteRule` does this by using the first group from the regular expression in the `RewriteCond`, this is what the `%1` accomplishes.  `$` are used to reference the groups of the `RewriteRule` expression, whereas `%` is used to to reference the groups of the `RewriteCond`. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: What does `[NC] `mean?